# Rcpp function for subsetting strings

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I was wondering if there was an `Rcpp` function which takes an `Rcpp::String` data type as input and returns a given character (by index) of the string. For example, extracting the character at index 0 of the string. This would be equivalent to the `string::at` method from the `string` header in c++. I have written this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

typedef std::vector<std::string> stringList;

int SplitGenotypesA(std::string s) {
    char a = s.at(0);
    int b = a - '0';
    return b;
}
```

But would prefer not to have to convert between `Rcpp::String` and `std::string` types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can feed an R vector of strings directly to C++ using `Rcpp::StringVector`. This will obviously handle single elements too.

Getting the nth character of the ith element of your vector is as simple as `vector[i][n]`.

So, without using `std::string` you can do this:

```cpp
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector SplitGenotypesA(Rcpp::StringVector R_character_vector)
{
  int number_of_strings = R_character_vector.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector result(number_of_strings);
  for(int i = 0; i < number_of_strings; ++i)
  {
    char a = R_character_vector[i][0];
    result[i] = a - '0';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now in R you can do:

```r
SplitGenotypesA("9C")
# [1] 9
```

or better yet,

```r
SplitGenotypesA(c("1A", "2B", "9C"))
# [1] 1 2 9
```

Which is even a little faster than the native R method of doing the same thing:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  R_method    = as.numeric(substr(c("1A", "2B", "9C"), 1, 1)), 
  Rcpp_method = SplitGenotypesA(c("1A", "2B", "9C")),
  times = 1000)

# Unit: microseconds
#         expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval
#     R_method 3.422 3.765 4.076722  4.107 4.108 46.881  1000
#  Rcpp_method 3.080 3.423 3.718779  3.765 3.765 32.509  1000
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was wondering if it was possible to do the a similar thing, but with a CharacterMatrix, subsetting a particular element of the matrix and character of the string like R_character_matrix(2, 3)[1] ?

Comment: Yes @sahwahn. If you have an r x c matrix of multi-character strings in R you can pass to C++ as a CharacterMatrix and access the ith character of any string in your matrix by matrix(r, c)[i]. Remember to use zero-indexing.